# How to designate a main class in Java

Tags: java, class

I am adapting a program which compiles OK; but when I try to run it I get an error window that says "no main classes found". I searched on your site for that type of problem (for NetBeans)and then tried a R click on my project in the Project window. Lagrange/properties/run  and the class shown was the one in my program. I clicked run in that window and got the same error message.
The program is pasted below:

```
package lagrange;

class MyMath {
    double xi[] = { 0, 0.5, 1, 1.5, 2 };
    double fi[] = { 1, 0.938470, 0.765198, 0.511828, 0.223891 };
    double x = 0.9;
    double f = aitken(x, xi, fi);

    // Method to carry out the Aitken recursions.
    public double aitken(double x, double xi[], double fi[]) {
        int n = xi.length - 1;
        double ft[] = (double[]) fi.clone();
        for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
            for (int j = 0; j < n - i; ++j) {
                ft[j] = (x - xi[j]) / (xi[i + j + 1] - xi[j]) * ft[j + 1]
                        + (x - xi[i + j + 1]) / (xi[j] - xi[i + j + 1]) * ft[j];
            }
        }
        return ft[0];
    }
}

public class Lagrange {
    public void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO code application logic here
        System.out.println("Interpolated value: " + f);
    }
}
```

Comment: it's `public static void main(...`

Answer (score 1):

It is `public static void main` - main method has to be **static**. And in your current code, you are declaring the `main` method in an inner class which is not static. This is not allowed and it will fail as

> static methods can only be declared in a static or top level type.

One solution that can work for you is provided below with these changes -

1. `main` method shifted to MyMath class.
2. `main` method being static does not have access to non-static members and hence an instance of MyMath is created and used to print the result.

---

```
package lagrange;

class MyMath {

    double xi[] = { 0, 0.5, 1, 1.5, 2 };
    double fi[] = { 1, 0.938470, 0.765198, 0.511828, 0.223891 };
    double x = 0.9;

    double f = aitken(x, xi, fi);

    // Method to carry out the Aitken recursions.

    public double aitken(double x, double xi[], double fi[]) {
        int n = xi.length - 1;
        double ft[] = (double[]) fi.clone();
        for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
            for (int j = 0; j < n - i; ++j) {
                ft[j] = (x - xi[j]) / (xi[i + j + 1] - xi[j]) * ft[j + 1]
                        + (x - xi[i + j + 1]) / (xi[j] - xi[i + j + 1]) * ft[j];
            }
        }
        return ft[0];
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Interpolated value: " + new MyMath().f);
    }

}
```

Comment: Thank You Pavan,  I was trying to insert an extra class and creating more problems for myself. I think I now understand the "Static" concept.